# How to make condition that jbutton can be clicked only if jtable row is selected

Tags: java, eclipse, jtable, h2

Hello guys I need your help, i am absolute beginner. This is my problem, i have JTable in which i have some data from database with columns like: Id, Movie, Category, and Director. With part 1 of code i am selecting that data in JTable and sending it to part 2 of code in order to show in other JFrame for purpose of editing data or deleting from Database. I am using H2 database for my project. Now, my question is next, is there an option to create condition for that JButton to be clickable only if row is selected in JTable, or when is not selected row on JTable, and you press that JButton, to receive error message, and not to go to second JFrame. The code is working right now, but if don't click anything on JTable fields in second JFrame are empty.

I hope that i was clear enough.

part one

```
       table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel)table.getModel();
            int selectedRowIndex=table.getSelectedRow();
            Id=(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 0).toString());
            Movie=(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 1).toString());
            Category=(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 2).toString());
            Director=(model.getValueAt(selectedRowIndex, 3).toString());

           }
           });
```

part two

```
    JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
    btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            EditDelete rmv=new EditDelete();
            rmv.txtId.setText(Id);
            rmv.txtMovie.setText(Movie);
            rmv.txtCategory.setText(Category);
            rmv.txtDirector.setText(Director);
            rmv.setVisible(true);
            frmMovieDatabase.dispose();

            }
    });
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: In the JButton ActionListener you can check if the table has something selected or not and take the right path (error or perform the deletion)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JTable API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#getSelectedRowCount()) has a method to get the number of selected rows: `getSelectedRowCount` that you can use on the JButton ActionListener to check if you can perform the deletion.

```
JButton btnDelete = new JButton("Delete");
    btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            if (table.getSelectedRowCount() != 0){
               // perform the deletion
            }else{
               // Throw an exception etc...
            }
        }
    });
```

If you have any questions about handling or retrieving  the selected values the page I linked above may have useful resources.